# Add border-bottom under the tr tag

Tags: html, css

I need to add border-bottom under the `<tr>` tag. Under first and last `<tr>` border should be None. How can I do it?

[image]

```css
table tr {
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>position</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>journalist</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Alex</td>
        <td>footballer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>driver</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>programmer</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to your styles this code:

```
tr+tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use `:first-child` & `:last-child` selector for targeting first and last child respectively. Like:

```
table tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

table tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

table tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

table tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>position</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Peter</td>
          <td>journalist</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Alex</td>
          <td>footballer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>driver</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Adam</td>
          <td>programmer</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the previous posted answer, you can keep your code even cleaner and free from repetition by targeting both the `:first-child` and `:last-child` in your css file at once:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

table tr:first-child, tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>position</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Peter</td>
          <td>journalist</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Alex</td>
          <td>footballer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>driver</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Adam</td>
          <td>programmer</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```